# How to "stack" touch events in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a feed of items that looks something like this:

[image]

**What I am trying to Achieve:**

When the user presses an item in the feed (represented by the black box), they will be brought to a separate page for that item. When the user clicks on the star icon, they can "favorite" the item.

**How I am trying to do it:**

I am currently trying to implement this by nesting two [TouchableOpacity](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity.html)'s (represented by the black boxes), where the inner/child TouchableOpacity has a `zIndex: 2` style applied to it.

The `zIndex` style does not seem to give a priority to the child container for touch events, so I was wondering if anyone knows how I can implement this pattern.  I think I might need to use the [PanResponder](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/panresponder.html), but it seems like a very verbose way to add this functionality.

Any comments or examples would be greatly appreciated ! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not simply nest a `TouchableOpacity` in your parent `TouchableOpacity` ? I've done a mock project and this below seems to work

```
<View>
    <TouchableOpacity 
      style = {{backgroundColor: 'red', height: 100}}
      onPress = {() => {console.log("PARENT METHOD")}}>
          //content
          <TouchableOpacity 
               style = {{width: 30, height: 30, backgroundColor: 'yellow',
                                      position: 'absolute', right: 5, bottom: 5}}
               onPress = {() => {console.log("CHILD METHOD")}}>
              //content
          </TouchableOpacity>
      </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

I've used logs and when pressing the small nested box, only child method is logged, and similarly for if i press the parent view.

[image]

Log output: showing independant touches

[image]

Let me know if this helps

Comment: yes, you are correct. there seems to be an issue with touch events in a library i am using, [react-native-snap-carousel](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel/)

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like below:

```
<View style={{flex-direction: "row"}}>
   <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.goToDetails.bind(this)}>
      </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
   <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.goToDetails.bind(this)}>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.favoriteItem.bind(this)}>
      </TouchableOpacity>
   </View>
</View>
```

Where you have two views in a row, first view has one `TouchableOpacity`, and the second view has two `TouchableOpacity`s in a a column (where first one is similar to previous `TouchableOpacity`, and the second is to favorite the item).

Should be structured like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank for this suggestion, I was thinking this as well. One drawback to this approach is that I lose the "opacity" feedback on the parent item when the user presses it (or the feedback will only highlight a section of the card).